# In shell script, colon(:) is being treated as a operator for variable creation

Tags: bash, shell

I have following snippet:

```
host="https://example.com"
port="80"
url="${host}:${port}"
echo $url
```

the output is:

```
:80ps://example.com
```

How can I escape the colon here. I also tried:

```
url="${host}\:${port}"
```

but it did not work.
Expected output is:

```
https://example.com:80
```

Comment: It seems like there's a Carriage Return character somewhere?

Comment: Check the end-of-line characters in your file. All in all, if you are to run each line individually, it works.

Comment: The carriage return at the end of the value of `host` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line when you output `url`, which results in the value of `port` overwriting the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 4):

You've most likely run into what I call the **Linefeed-Limbo**.
If I copy the code you provided from StackOverflow and run it on my machine (bash version 4.4.19(1)), then it outputs correctly

```
user@host:~$ cat script.sh
host="https://example.com"
port="80"
url="${host}:${port}"
echo $url

user@host:~$ bash script.sh
https://example.com:80
```

## What is Linefeed-Limbo?

Different operating systems use different ASCII symbols to represent when a new line occurs in a text, such as a script. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) gives a good introduction.

As you can see, Unix and Unix-like systems use the single character `\n`, also called a "Line Feed". Windows, as well as other systems, use `\r\n`, so a "carriage return" followed by a "line feed".

What happens now is when you write a script on Windows on an editor such as notepad, what you write is `host="example.com"\r\n`. When you copy this file into Linux, Linux interprets the `\r` as if it were part of the script, since only `\n` is considered a new line. And indeed, when I change my newline style to DOS-style, I get the exact output you get.

## How can I fix this?

You have several options to fix this issue.

### Converting the script (with `dos2unix`)

Since all you need to do is replacing every instance of `\r\n` with `\n`, you could use any text-editing software you want. However, if you like simple solutions, then `dos2unix` (and its sister `unix2dos`) might be what you looking for:

```
user@host:~$ dos2unix script.sh
dos2unix: converting file script.sh to Unix format...
```

That's it. Run your file now and you will see it behaves well.

### Encoding the source-file correctly

By using a more advanced text editor such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org), you can define which style of newline you would like to use.

[image: Notepad++ in CRLF-mode]
[image: Notepad++ in LF-mode]

By changing the newline-type to whichever system you intend to run your script on, you will not run into any problems like this anymore.

## Bonus round: Why does it output `:80ps://example.com`?

To understand why your output is like this, you have to look at what your script is doing, and what `\r` means.

Try thinking of your terminal as an old-fashioned typewriter. Returning the carriage means you start writing on the left again. Making a "new line" means sliding the paper. These two things are seperate, and I think that's why some systems decided to use these two characters as a logical "new line".

But I digress. Let's look at the first line, `host="https://example.com"\r`.
What this means when printed is "Print https://example.com, then put the carriage back at the start". When you then print `:80\r`, it doesn't start after ".com", it starts at the beginning of the line, because that's where you (unknowingly) told the cursor to go. it then overwites the first few characters, resulting in ":80ps://example.com" to be written. Keep in mind that after 80, you again placed a carriage return symbol, so any new text you would have written ends up overwriting the beginning again.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me, try to remove carriage returns in variables and then try.

```
new_host=$(echo "$host" |  tr -d '\r')
new_port=$(echo "$port" |  tr -d '\r')
new_url="${new_host}:${new_port}"
```